# How to link another HTML file onto HTML

Tags: javascript, html, href

I am trying to create an expand on click feature on my website. When the user clicks on the button, something is displayed.

I know I can use JS to make the div show up, but my HTML code is long, so I don't want to copy the entire thing there. I know I can also use the  tag, but I don't want my page to refresh.

```js
 function findPressure() {
  var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
  ifrm.setAttribute("src","/Users/lunapark/Documents/antoine_equation/antoine_pressure.html");
  document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
 }
```

```html
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <button onClick="findPressure()">Solve for Pressure</button>
    <button onClick="findTemp()">Solve for Temperature</button>
  </div>
```

As you can see here, I used iframe, which I am not in favor of. Is there some way I can link the existing HTML to my main HTML and not have it refresh on a web page?

Comment: Try to use [ajax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_ajax)

Comment: HTML files can't be linked like JS or stylesheets. You can use AJAX to load the content from the server.

Comment: Better Create one `<Iframe>` Element and Change its source on each button click.  - In this approach iframe will get refresh not the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways of doing this - upgrade to Vue.js for example. Or jQuery load() is pretty good for this kind of thing too. https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I'd rather recommend a simple `fetch`.